# postgres - how to alter a column with timestamp?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In postgre sql - How do I alter a column which has time stamp.
Currently the column is defined as below -
  `creation_time timestamp(6) with time zone`
and i want to make the above column not null also.  So i have tried below but had no luck

`ALTER TABLE my_table ALTER COLUMN creation_time TYPE timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL;`

What is the correct syntax ?

Comment: "Had no luck".. what does that mean? Wrong syntax? or something else? Basically you can't alter a column to be not nullable, if it contains nulls, so my recomendation is - loss the null values and then try again. Also, after quick google search, this it the syntax: `ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name SET NOT NULL;`

Comment: right.. wrong syntax. thanks sharing right syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)

```sql
alter table my_table alter creation_time set not null;
```